# Selective functionality in Javascript libraries with Require.js

Tags: javascript, js-amd

In [net.tutplus tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/next-generation-javascript-with-amd-and-requirejs-new-on-premium/), Andrew Burgess mentions a Rebecca Murphey's comment "that she would love a JavaScript world where you could pick and choose where you get your functionality: you could get your DOM manipulation from jQuery, your array utilities from YUI, your UI widgets from Dojo, etc.", then he adds "Trying this today would be a nightmare. But, guess what? AMD solves this". Unfortunetly the article is just a preview so the full version requires premium access. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/issues/14) sums it all.

> Here's what I said in the tutorial:
>
> *In her talk “Modern JavaScript” at JSConf 2011, Rebecca Murphey said
>   that she would love a JavaScript world where you could pick and choose
>   where you get your functionality: you could get your DOM manipulation
>   from jQuery, your array utilities from YUI, your UI widgets from Dojo,
>   etc. Trying this today would be a nightmare. But, guess what? AMD
>   solves this.*
>
> Now, I'm just realizing that when I said "AMD solves this," I made it
>   sound like the problem was already solved. What I meant to say,
>   however, was that if the library makers would use the AMD pattern for
>   their libraries, and make each part of their libraries a separate
>   module, then we'd be able to, as you say, pick DOM stuff from jQuery,
>   array utils from YUI, etc. Right now, that isn't really possible,
>   although I understand Dojo is using AMD now. And it's great to hear
>   that jQuery is now AMD compatible!
>
> TL;DR: It's not possible right now. I hope it will be in the future